# While loop slowing down?

Tags: java

I am trying to print a date every second or so while waiting for a condition to be met.
This is the code I came up with:

```
boolean whileControl = true;
int whileCount = 0;

while (whileControl == true) {

if (isTrue() == true) {

    whileControl = false;
    //stuff
    break;

} else {

    whileCount += 1;
    if (whileCount >= 1000000) {

        whileCount = 0;
        String date = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));  
        System.out.println(date);

    }
}
```

Now, this works the first few times, but, at some point it slows down and stops working (I am not sure if it completely stops, but surely it is not printing as fast as I'd like).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes. A [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). You are creating a lot of `Date` instances, eventually `gc` happens.

Comment: Use `Thread.sleep` - but a `Timer` is better

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, do I need to call the timer outside of the while loop and then disable it when the condition is met, or I am completely in the wrong direction?

Comment: may I ask for your aim? or more exactly:  what do you mean by "every second or so"?

Comment: @moneydhaze I want to know whether the function is working properly or not. Also, I'd like to know when the condition is met (although I could probably just print the date when that happens)

Comment: checking if the function is working could also be done by printing whileCount, and printing date once right after, right? the next thing is that you should have "some kind of idea" what the condition is... printing something to log takes time and slows stuff down, creating objects too, also it's depending on your computer when this condition will be hit, the only thing you know it should be after 1000001 iterations, so what do you try to accomplish with this?

Comment: "Properly" is an ambiguous term - what really are your goals with this program ? Speed depends on so many things. You are creating so many objects which needs to be GCed - so later slow down is expected. You need to print the count/sec or something similar to make an objective comparison rather than saying "slower than you would like".

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the slowdown is due to `isTrue()` being called too many times and got throttled, because you are checking this condition without any wait time between any two consecutive checks.

Try:

```
int whileCount = 0;
while (true) {
    if (isTrue()) {
        //stuff
        break;
    }

    whileCount++;
    if (whileCount >= 1000000) {
        whileCount = 0;            
        System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
    }
    // Sleep 1 second before another check
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: What if "if (whileCount >= 1000000)" loop itself takes more than 1 second or close to but less than 1 second - you need to account for that - if you really want to run this loop once every second.

Comment: but isn't the stack releasing any relevant memory and then using it again when calling isTrue() again, like in cpp?

Comment: @AriSingh he never said he want to print it every sec

Comment: Adding a `thread.sleep(333)` inside the else (maybe omitted here?), and checking if `whileCount >= 3`, seems to be a nice balance between checks and prints. Also I moved `String date` outside of the `while`. Not sure how it compares to timers yet.

Comment: @moneydhaze That's the first thing he said: "I am trying to print a date every second or so"

Comment: @moneydhaze I want to print it "every second or so". So yeah, small errors are fine.

Comment: But this code could result in big error - It could take more than 2 seconds to print depending how long the loop takes - unless you call 100% deviation "small"

Comment: The point is we don't know what's in `isTrue()` call. For example if it does a remote service call the it could get throttled due to high tps and becomes slow.

Comment: @wz366 is true compares two lists (each one contains 200 strings roughly), if they are the same, true gets returned. I don't think it will cause much of a problem really.

Comment: ok, sry then, usually if i hear the "there also could be" my ears go down &.&, it's hard to reassure that the the print is actually called every second :|

Comment: @AriSingh I agree that if the print statement takes 1ms then after 2000 print statements here (after roughly 1000000 * 2000 seconds), the total time elapsed could be 2 seconds off. But you missed the point that it's not 2 seconds off between every two prints, it's still 1ms off between two prints.

Comment: @A.Pecora Try to print whileCount instead of time in your code and see if while loop gets slow. Delete this line `String date = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));`.